# Change Thunderbird's quote format to use greater-than signs (">") instead of margin/border, and bottom-posting

Tags: email, thunderbird, citations, html-mail

I'm a new Thunderbird user, I've decided to pick it up after changes in Yahoo Mail (so I'm open to suggestions of other mail clients too).

When I reply to an e-mail, I get the quoted text in a `format=flowed` style with borders:

[image: screenshot]

If I reply in plain-text mode, I get the reply in the format I want:

[image: screenshot]

(I assume the colors won't be sent and are just "syntax highlighting", right?) but I'd like to keep using HTML for features like inline images.

Is there any way I can get that same style of old-school quotes so I can write in [bottom-posting format](http://mailformat.dan.info/quoting/bottom-posting.html) while still using HTML mode? If there is some template somewhere that I'd have to edit, I'd be ok with having to do that.

Comment: Nice choice of example emails ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek http://i.imgur.com/EvQKIi0.jpg

Answer (score 4):

There's an [official tutorial](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Quote_bars) about that. "Quote colors" extension is no longer useful for newest versions, so one have to edit .css files by himself.

Also i'd also recommend taking a look at the [similar question at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173505/how-do-i-make-thunderbirds-reply-format-look-like-outlooks) (Thundebird is cross-platform as well as its extensions)

Comment: I've tried the suggestions at that article - with or without that "Quote Colors" extension (which is actually unsupported for the current version), and I only get the bars to disappear on HTML mode, but not only there's no option to use `>` instead, also the indentation space remais, for some reason. The AskUbuntu tips helped removing the bar, but seemingly it's not possible to write a template to have `>` quotes in HTML mode :( +1 though.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to edit css files by yourself, as it's written in the tutorial. "put the following code in your "userContent.css" and "prefs.js" files, respectively."

Comment: That's what I did, and what I meant by "with or without [the extension]". In any case those tips should only help to remove the bar, right? The SmartTemplate and ReFwdFormatter extensions helped with that, but there doesn't seem to be a way to have `>`-quotes in HTML mode (as opposed to text mode) replies, right?